# memcpy + pointers + java

Tags: java, arrays, memcpy

I have seen there is no question that specifically reply to this combination of parameters:

Java + memcpy + pointers.

My background of C/C++ is probably biasing me.
In C++ I can do this:

```
memcpy (Destination, Source, length_data);
```

and Destination and Source can be just two memory locations.
Is there a way to do it in Java with arrays of primitive types?

All the realizations of

```
Arrays.copyOf
Arrays.copyOfRange
```

are basically doing half the job. In the sense that, you can specify the amount of data or a given range, but all of them give back one Array, they do not modify an existing one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't recommend it but there is an equivalent which is Unsafe.copyMemory() which can be used to copy from an address/object to an address/object an arbitary length of bytes.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was referring to copy of arrays.
But your comment can be really helpful for generic memcpy actions.

Comment: arrays are objects, you can call Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset() to get the offset of the first value and arrayIndexScale(Class) to find the size of each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thank you. You fully replied to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have pointers the way that C/C++ do.

There's System.arraycopy(); have a look at the javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify an existing array using [System.arraycopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

> If the src and dest arguments refer to the same array object, then the
>   copying is performed as if the components at positions srcPos through
>   srcPos+length-1 were first copied to a temporary array with length
>   components and then the contents of the temporary array were copied
>   into positions destPos through destPos+length-1 of the destination
>   array.

Of course it's not a perfect analoguous operation, given the lack of pointers in Java.